# Формирование запроса

Tags: mysql

есть запрос

```
SELECT source_id FROM tables WHERE DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL ? DAY) <= data;'
```

также есть таблица в которой есть поля id и name как вместо source_id подставлять значение колонки name по ключу id
за любую информацию буду благодарен

Comment: видимо вам нужен join, если я правильно понял вопрос. https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)

Comment: это я уже понял я немогу нормально запрос пересоздать

Comment: `select name from tables t join таблица Т on Т.id=t.source_id where ...`